# how to write test with enzyme for material ui Radio

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, material-ui, enzyme

I used RadioGroup from material UI and want to write test code with jest and enzyme
here is my code:

```
import React from "react";
import Radio from "@material-ui/core/Radio";
import RadioGroup from "@material-ui/core/RadioGroup";
import FormControlLabel from "@material-ui/core/FormControlLabel";
import FormControl from "@material-ui/core/FormControl";
import FormLabel from "@material-ui/core/FormLabel";  


const ThemeColorSwitcher = ({setDarkState,theme: { _theme, _light, _dark }}) => {
   
  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setDarkState(event.target.value);
  };

  

  return (
    <FormControl component="fieldset">
      <FormLabel component="legend">{_theme}</FormLabel>
      <RadioGroup
        aria-label="theme"
        name="theme1"
        value={darkState}
        onChange={handleChange}      >
        <FormControlLabel value="false" control={<Radio />} label={_light} />
        <FormControlLabel value="true" control={<Radio />} label={_dark} />
      </RadioGroup>
    </FormControl>
  );
};

export default ThemeColorSwitcher;
```

and it's my test , but I can't find the props to check that Radio is clicked or not?

```
import React from "react";
import ThemeColorSwitcher from "./ThemeColorSwitcher";
import FormControl from "@material-ui/core/FormControl";
import Radio from "@material-ui/core/Radio";
import {
  createMount,
  createShallow,
  createRender,
} from "@material-ui/core/test-utils";

describe("<ThemeColorSwitcher />", () => {
  it("simulates click on radio", () => {
    const mount = createMount();
    const wrapper = mount(<ThemeColorSwitcher />);
    const radio = wrapper.find(Radio).last();
    radio.simulate("click");
    expect(radio.props().checked).toBe(true);
  });
});
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, we need to trigger the onChange event. For that, you can run the following code.

```
const event = {
  target: { value: 'true' }
} as React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>;
wrapper.find(RadioGroup).props().onChange(event, 'true');
```

This will trigger the onChange event and it will change the value.